# What ports do you need, to run an SRCDS server?

Tags: port-forwarding, port

SRCDS stands for *Source Dedicated Server*.

I want to run an SRCDS on my Windows XP machine. I've forwarded the ports: 
1200; 27000-28000

[The server run script](http://pastebin.com/Huxt8kLp)
[dinodday\cfg\server.cfg](http://pastebin.com/HttWvwS1)
[Server's log file (at start)](http://pastebin.com/RPvJDGZ3)
[Status command's output from console](http://pastebin.com/Py772Wke)
[Server's log file after someone connected (me)](http://pastebin.com/DY7HB9Z2)

[Where, and how I see my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25vKx.png)

Yet, I can't see my server in the game (it's a Dino D-Day server). I only see it as a "Steam group server" in the main menu, but I'm pretty sure that it cannot be seen from outside (in the master browser.)

**There is NO firewall installed on the server.** (Ports are forwarded in the router.)

Comment: have you tried connecting from systems within the lan?

Comment: Yes, it works great with LAN, and it works if I give my friend the direct IP of the server. But no one can see it in the server browser.

Comment: Added the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the default port is 27015 according to [this](http://planethalflife.gamespy.com/View.php?view=HL2Guides.Detail&id=4&game=3) but you can set your own.

Comment: I'll try installing openWRT on the router... but I guess 27015 is open.

Comment: Port is open 100%. But the server still can't be seen from the server browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your server run script, you are binding to a local IP address:

```
+ip 192.168.1.16
```

You either have to remove that or replace it with your public IP (see https://www.whatismyip.com/).

Comment: When the server is behind a NAT, it is correct and even required to bind to the private address. (The server behind a NAT only has the private address assigned to its network interface, and only sees the private address in incoming packets.)

Comment: That is correct. However, in this case I think (correct me if I'm wrong) the server reports the IP specified here to the master server which in turn gives out the server list to the clients. A local IP will do no good here. This might be the reason why the OP's server doesn't show up in the server browser, yet can be connected to when the IP is entered directly.